# Need an example program in scala for spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need an example program in scala which explains how to handle with dataframes. I am from python background and very much new to scala. In python we generally write like this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['a','b','c'],[1,2,3]])
print(df)
```

I have seen many scala spark tutorials. But they are dealing with very advanced stuff. I need only hello world program of Spark data frame. I am expecting some program like this.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object Hello_world {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val df = sparkDataframe("[a,b,c],[1,2,3]")
    print(df)
  }
}
```

Comment: Try "spark dataframe scala tutorial" on google

Comment: Do you think I haven't tried. I want this not only for me but for everyone who is starting with spark.

Comment: Arguments about this will not bring any benefits. Here you are supposed to ask questions and I do not see any question in this like what exactly is the problem that you are facing when trying whatever you are claiming to have tried. And if your question is a plain - where can I find a tutorial for Spark with scala, then it is simple - SO is not a place for such questions.

Comment: Well... thanks for reminding me, just added my downvote. On a serious note, I would really like to help you, if you are having some specific problem which I can actually understand and answer. But, this question in its current form does not tell anyone anything about what your problem is. And frankly, it does not give any impression of effort. Now its up to you.

Comment: If you want to know what have I tried, I followed these tuts. https://www.dezyre.com/apache-spark-tutorial/spark-tutorial

Comment: This seems like a basic spark tutorial and is pretty decent. So, what is the problem that you are suck with?

Comment: Thank you very much. I was just expecting a hello world program to use spark dataframe in scala. What information do you need.

Comment: I want to convery a 2D list to spark dataframe like in pandas. I was asking the same.

Comment: well... this is the hello world program. The thing is you are dealing with Spark, which is a distributed computing platform. And it is inherently complex compared to using pandas. You can also look for Spark with Python instead of looking into Scala. http://www.sparktutorials.net/Getting+Started+with+Apache+Spark+DataFrames+in+Python+and+Scala

Comment: We cannot fix some random tutorials that you found somewhere online. If those tutorials turned out to be incomprehensible and useless, then it's not our problem, and it's not Spark's problem either. Have you tried the official Apache Spark documentation? It seems that they [have hello-world-like standalone applications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications) in the very first "Quick Start" chapter.

Comment: See the answer mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I've never worked on Python Dataframes, hence I didn't completely understood your example, but I can give you a simple example to get working with Scala's spark DF.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

  val masterAddress = "local[*]"
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master(masterAddress).getOrCreate()

object Hello_world {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    import spark.implicits._

    case class applySchema(name:String,rollNumber:Int)
    val makeRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(("a",1),("b",2),("c",3)))
    val makeDF = makeRDD.map(data => applySchema(data._1,data._2)).toDF
    makeDF.show(false)
  }
}
```

This results in

```
+----+----------+
|name|rollNumber|
+----+----------+
|a   |1         |
|b   |2         |
|c   |3         |
+----+----------+
```

Explanation: We are creating a case class (applySchema) to define the schema, then we are creating an RDD, then we are applying schema to the RDD and converting it to a Dataframe by using (toDF function).

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed.